# Automate the update of a pivot table in Excel via Power Automate Web

Tags: excel, automation, pivot-table, refresh, power-automate

I have an Excel File that displays a pivot table. The pivot table drags its info from a connexion to a database.
Each day, i have to go to this Excel, click on refresh to get the new data from the Pivot table.

I wondered if there is a way to update automatically with power Automate the click button "Refresh".
Something like :
When I receive a specific email > Open the Excel file (at this path, and it will local or on teams folder) > Click on Refresh pivot table > Close the excel file.

I watched some videos but couldn't find anything. i find a way to update the pivot table when we just open the excel file but i don't know how to open and close the Excel file on Power Automate.
Also I'm using Power Automate Web (and not Desktop and I won't be able to use it).

Let me know if you have a solution,

A big thanks,

- try to find Excel in Actions (but it's only online Excel. I found the Onedrive actions that seems good but there is no open and close file to automatically launch the refresh)